# Alamofire and Response allHTTPHeaderFields Issue

Tags: swift, swift4, alamofire, urlrequest

I'm talking with one API in iOS app using Alamofire for my network request.
So this api, in which i don't have access, at one response it sends me some headers with some values

For example

```
Set-Cookie: test1
Set-Cookie: test2
Set-Cookie: test3
```

but when i print `allHTTPHeaderFields` it prints me only the last "Set-Cookie" which is "test3" and the other 2 tests i lose them.

Is there any way to get each of the responses?

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19066577/6541007). You may need to use `HTTPCookieStorage`.

Comment: @OOPer still gives me the last cookie :/ 
although postman gives me all the cookies!

Comment: Then it's beyond my knowledge. Hope you can solve your issue soon.